# Need help converting a for loop to lapply or sapply

Tags: r

I am working on R and learning how to code.  I have written a piece of code, utilizing a for loop and I find it very slow.  I was wondering if I can get some assistance to convert it to use either the sapply or lapply function.  Here is my working R code:

```
library(dplyr)
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332)   {
      files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)   #creates a list of files
      dat <- data.frame()                             #creates an empty data frame
      for (i in seq_along(files_list)) {
            #loops through the files, rbinding them together
            dat <- rbind(dat, read.csv(files_list[i]))
      }
      dat_subset <- filter(dat, dat$ID %in% id) #subsets the rows that match the 'ID' argument
      mean(dat_subset[, pollutant], na.rm=TRUE)      #identifies the Mean of a Pollutant
}

pollutantmean("specdata", "sulfate", 1:10)
```

This code takes almost 20 seconds to return, which is unacceptable for 332 records.  Imagine if I have a dataset with 10K records and wanted to get the mean of those variables?

Comment: If this is for the Coursera R programming course, search here for `[r] pollutantmean` and you will find dozens of posts with good solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `rbind` all elements in a list using `do.call`, and you can read in all the files into that list using `lapply`:

```
mean(
  filter( # here's the filter that will be applied to the rbind-ed data
    do.call("rbind", # call "rbind" on all elements of a list 
            lapply( # create a list by reading in the files from list.files()
              # add any necessary args to read.csv:
              list.files("[::DIR_PATH::]"), function(x) read.csv(file=x, ...)
            ) 
    )
  ), ID %in% id)$pollutant, # make sure id is replaced with what you want
na.rm = TRUE
)
```

Comment: Tks for your recommendation and suggestion, however, the coma after $pollutant is generating an unexpected token error in R

Comment: could be a typo, its hard to tell without a reproducible chunk of data, sorry

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is slow because you are incrementally growing your dataframe in the loop. One way to do this using `dplyr` and `map_df` from `purrr` can be

```
library(dplyr)
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332)   {

    files_list <- list.files(directory, full.names=TRUE)  
    purrr::map_df(files_list, read.csv) %>%
                  filter(ID %in% id) %>%
                  summarise_at(pollutant, mean, na.rm = TRUE)

}
```